# Select making Vue component buggy

Tags: html, vuejs3

I am making a select component with select and options(basic html) but when I close the option the ">" turns red.

```
<template>

    <div class="input-sm">

      <select>

        <option>Select a type</option>

        <option v-for="type in store.itemTypes.value" :key="type.id">{{ type.title }}</option>

      </select>

    </div>

  </template>
  
<script setup>

  import * as store from '@/store';

 </script>
```